# Newbie git error when cloning a repository

Tags: git, github

I'm completly new to git system. I'd like to clone this nice plugin for bootstrap. [Here is](https://github.com/storborg) the user page and this should be the url of `.git` file:

```
git clone https://github.com/storborg/bootstrap.git
(asks for credentials... used mine)
```

Got:

> Fatal: https://github.com/storborg/bootstrap/info/refs not found: did
>   you run git update-server-info on the server?

I don't know how to deal with this error and how to solve it. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means the repo doesn't exist

```
$ git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'bar'...
fatal: https://github.com/foo/bar.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

The repository you are trying to clone has been deleted or renamed: https://github.com/storborg/bootstrap (it's a 404)

Comment: Sounds strange since i can read: "storborg closed pull request 2 on storborg/bootstrap 4 days ago". Seems like it was active 4 days ago?

Comment: deleting/renaming repos is a relatively common occurrence - you could ask storborg where it went perhaps :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want get Twitter's Bootstap project?

Please try: git clone https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git

Comment: Nope, it's a plugin for bootstrap, thanks. I already have bootstrap.